# List dates defined by a set of rules

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm needing to create a form where the user can input a set of rules, and have returned a list of dates that match these rules.

For example:

'First day in December this year' => 2020-12-01
'First Monday in May this year' => 2020-05-04

I have managed to achieve this by using DateTime and giving it a relative date:

```
$ordinal = 'first';
$unit = 'day';
$month = 'december';

$date = new DateTime($ordinal . ' ' . $unit . ' of ' . $month . ' this year' );
```

The ordinal, unit and month are currently being selected by dropdown menus on the front-end.

The issue I'm facing is when multiple dates could match the rules. For example:

'The first weekend in December this year' should return 2020-12-05 & 2020-12-06.
'Every weekend in march' should return the date of each Saturday and Sunday during March.

The method I used for single dates obviously does not work. When changing my `unit` to 'weekend', I get the following error message:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: DateInterval::__construct() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given`

I've had a look at DateInterval, but doubtful this is what I need. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: My apologies. I've added the code that works, and the error message I receive when it should return more than one date.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across RRUles which allows me to set a number of rules to generate dates that match them. This was able to help me generate the dates for the sort of rules am working with.

Here are a couple of links for anyone who may be interested:

https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule

https://github.com/rlanvin/php-rrule